# Creating dataframes using ifelse

Tags: r

I have been stuck on this for the last two days - I have tried so many different things, so I'm going back to square 1 and hoping someone cleverer than me can help me out.

I am trying to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 c.d.Sex.        yposition  group1  group2           p.value asterisk
1     Male 365.444428021269 NCS_Con  CS_Con  0.99138011109024       NA
2     Male 514.373873256316 NCS_Con  CS_PNS 0.763891183622571       NA
3     Male 580.912393257263 NCS_Con NCS_PNS 0.944085783114498       NA
```

However, nothing is in the right order (see below).

```
c.d.Sex. <- c(rep("Male", 3)) #so far so good
```

Here is where things get sticky, but bear with me to the end:

```
yposition2 <-ifelse(grepl("^CS_Con$",corttestunitedmutated2$Treatment_Status) & grepl("^Male$", corttestunitedmutated2$c.d.Sex.), paste(corttestunitedmutated2$ypos),
             ifelse(grepl("^CS_PNS$",corttestunitedmutated2$Treatment_Status) & grepl("^Male$", corttestunitedmutated2$c.d.Sex.), paste(corttestunitedmutated2$ypos),                                                                             
             ifelse(grepl("^NCS_PNS$",corttestunitedmutated2$Treatment_Status) & grepl("^Male$", corttestunitedmutated2$c.d.Sex.), paste(corttestunitedmutated2$ypos), NA)))
```

Next step:

```
yposition <- na.omit(yposition2)
group1 <- c(rep("NCS_Con", 3))
group2 <- c("CS_Con","CS_PNS","NCS_PNS")
```

Then:

```
p.value2 <- ifelse(grepl("^Male$", posthocsepkeep2$Sexgroup1) & grepl("^Male$", posthocsepkeep2$Sexgroup2) & 
                    grepl("^NCS_Con$|^NCS_PNS$", posthocsepkeep2$Treatment_Statusgroup1) & grepl("^NCS_Con$|^NCS_PNS$", posthocsepkeep2$Treatment_Statusgroup2), paste(posthocsepkeep2$p.value),
            ifelse(grepl("^Male$", posthocsepkeep2$Sexgroup1) & grepl("^Male$", posthocsepkeep2$Sexgroup2) & 
                   grepl("^NCS_Con$|^CS_Con$", posthocsepkeep2$Treatment_Statusgroup1) & grepl("^NCS_Con$|^CS_Con$", posthocsepkeep2$Treatment_Statusgroup2), paste(posthocsepkeep2$p.value),    
             ifelse(grepl("^Male$", posthocsepkeep2$Sexgroup1) & grepl("^Male$", posthocsepkeep2$Sexgroup2) & 
                    grepl("^NCS_Con$|^CS_PNS$", posthocsepkeep2$Treatment_Statusgroup1) & grepl("^NCS_Con$|^CS_PNS$", posthocsepkeep2$Treatment_Statusgroup2), paste(posthocsepkeep2$p.value), 
                                 NA)))

p.value <- na.omit(p.value2)

asterisk <- ifelse(p.value<0.10 & p.value>0.05, paste("~"),
            ifelse(p.value<0.05 & p.value>0.001, paste("∆"),     
            ifelse(p.value<0.001 & p.value>0.0001, paste("∆∆"),
            ifelse(p.value>0.0001, paste("∆∆∆"), NA))))
```

And finally:

```
malestats.test1 <- data.frame(c.d.Sex., yposition, group1, group2, p.value, asterisk)
malestats.test1$yposition <- as.numeric(as.character(malestats.test1$yposition))

malestats.test1omit <- na.omit(malestats.test1)

maletestnrow2 <- nrow(malestats.test1omit)
```

The problem is that `ifelse()` runs sequentially as I understand it, but I can't put the data in the "correct" order because it looks like this:

```
corttestunitedmutated2
  Treatment_Status c.d.Sex.  N     mean        sd       se     ypos
1          NCS_Con   Female  9 793.1851 139.47968 46.49323 841.6783
2          NCS_Con     Male 10 415.2965 183.04720 57.88461 475.1811
3          NCS_PNS   Female  9 491.7112 115.47114 38.49038 532.2016
4          NCS_PNS     Male  9 337.3543  78.27023 26.09008 365.4444
5           CS_Con   Female  9 828.8667 176.11956 58.70652 889.5732
6           CS_Con     Male 10 470.6272 132.01445 41.74663 514.3739
7           CS_PNS   Female  9 617.1462 167.48928 55.82976 674.9760
8           CS_PNS     Male 10 521.3967 181.88043 57.51564 580.9124
```

and

```
posthocsepkeep2
        p.value Sexgroup1 Sexgroup2 Treatment_Statusgroup1 Treatment_Statusgroup2
1  1.169197e-01    Female    Female                 CS_Con                 CS_PNS
2  1.216136e-04    Female      Male                 CS_Con                 CS_Con
3  6.449545e-03    Female      Male                 CS_Con                 CS_PNS
4  9.996151e-01    Female    Female                 CS_Con                NCS_Con
5  3.422337e-03    Female    Female                 CS_Con                NCS_PNS
6  7.786261e-06    Female      Male                 CS_Con                NCS_Con
7  4.453535e-05    Female      Male                 CS_Con                NCS_PNS
8  4.484333e-01    Female      Male                 CS_PNS                 CS_Con
9  8.642252e-01    Female      Male                 CS_PNS                 CS_PNS
10 2.709620e-01    Female    Female                 CS_PNS                NCS_Con
11 6.521321e-01    Female    Female                 CS_PNS                NCS_PNS
12 1.313370e-01    Female      Male                 CS_PNS                NCS_Con
13 6.305701e-03    Female      Male                 CS_PNS                NCS_PNS
14 9.938626e-01      Male      Male                 CS_Con                 CS_PNS
15 6.704281e-04      Male    Female                 CS_Con                NCS_Con
16 9.999830e-01      Male    Female                 CS_Con                NCS_PNS
17 9.913801e-01      Male      Male                 CS_Con                NCS_Con
18 5.595949e-01      Male      Male                 CS_Con                NCS_PNS
19 1.864489e-02      Male    Female                 CS_PNS                NCS_Con
20 9.998657e-01      Male    Female                 CS_PNS                NCS_PNS
21 7.638912e-01      Male      Male                 CS_PNS                NCS_Con
22 1.659374e-01      Male      Male                 CS_PNS                NCS_PNS
23 9.693650e-03    Female    Female                NCS_Con                NCS_PNS
24 4.633011e-05    Female      Male                NCS_Con                NCS_Con
25 1.166243e-04    Female      Male                NCS_Con                NCS_PNS
26 9.493203e-01    Female      Male                NCS_PNS                NCS_Con
27 3.931364e-01    Female      Male                NCS_PNS                NCS_PNS
28 9.440858e-01      Male      Male                NCS_Con                NCS_PNS
```

So, returning to the dataframe from the top. This is what I get:

```
 c.d.Sex.        yposition  group1  group2           p.value asterisk
    1     Male 365.444428021269 NCS_Con  CS_Con  0.99138011109024       NA
    2     Male 514.373873256316 NCS_Con  CS_PNS 0.763891183622571       NA
    3     Male 580.912393257263 NCS_Con NCS_PNS 0.944085783114498       NA
```

This is what it should be (look at the yposition):

```
 c.d.Sex.        yposition  group1  group2           p.value asterisk
    1     Male 514.373873256316 NCS_Con  CS_Con  0.99138011109024        NA
    2     Male 580.912393257263 NCS_Con  CS_PNS  0.763891183622571       NA
    3     Male 365.444428021269 NCS_Con  NCS_PNS 0.944085783114498       NA
```

But, if I change the order of the `yposition`, the `pvalue` order is all wrong.

This is for a script that will eventually sit in a for loop that I will use for all my data. The  Treatment_Status groups will always be the same, but I can't guarantee what order it will be in. So really I need to use grepl to identify the correct name.  Also, once I get it working I can apply this new knowledge to the other dataframes I need to create within one iteration.

I feel that maybe combining `corttestunitedmutated2` and `posthocsepkeep2` into one dataframe would make sense? At least that is what I have (unsuccessfully) tried. If you have a better idea, please let me know!

Note: the `yposition` refers to the contents of `group2` of the final dataframe.

I hope this makes sense. I've been staring at this damn screen for too long trying to figure it out.

Comment: are the numeric columns actually numeric or are they factors (`data.frame` natively converts all character columns to factor)?

Comment: I didn't make it all the way through your code, but thinking that whatever it is you're doing with nested `ifelse`s, you could probably do less painfully with `case_when`

Comment: At the very least, can you use `dput` to share your objects? To do so effectively, we need to run your code and for that we need to replicate your data. Happy to help but do not want to manually type in your data objects. Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a small example and explain what you are trying to do and show expected output for it? Create an example with 10 rows and only 2-3 important columns for the question which would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out in the end:

The key was the `match` function for `stattest2_keep$matchypos`!

I have only just started learning how to use r in the last month and it's like I am trying to speak English with a vocabulary of only 50 words. I can say what I need to say but it is clunky and imprecise.

Here is the full script:

```
male_filterbysex <- filter(posthocsepkeep, grepl('Male', Sexgroup1) & grepl('Male', Sexgroup2))

corttestunitedmutated_filter_male <- filter(corttestunitedmutated, grepl("Male", c.d.Sex.))

stattest2_filterbyNCS_Con <- filter(male_filterbysex, grepl('NCS_Con', Treatment_Statusgroup1) | grepl('NCS_Con', Treatment_Statusgroup2))


stattest2_addgroup1col <- mutate(stattest2_filterbyNCS_Con, group1 = ifelse(grepl("NCS_Con", Treatment_Statusgroup1) | grepl("NCS_Con", Treatment_Statusgroup2), "NCS_Con",
                                                                            ifelse(grepl("NCS_PNS", Treatment_Statusgroup1) | grepl("NCS_PNS", Treatment_Statusgroup2), "NCS_PNS",
                                                                                   ifelse(grepl("CS_Con", Treatment_Statusgroup1) | grepl("CS_Con", Treatment_Statusgroup2), "CS_Con",
                                                                                          ifelse(grepl("CS_PNS", Treatment_Statusgroup1) | grepl("CS_PNS", Treatment_Statusgroup2), "CS_PNS", NA)))))

stattest2_addgroup2col <- mutate(stattest2_addgroup1col, group2 = ifelse(grepl("^NCS_PNS$", Treatment_Statusgroup1) | grepl("^NCS_PNS$", Treatment_Statusgroup2), "NCS_PNS",
                                                                         ifelse(grepl("^CS_Con$", Treatment_Statusgroup1) | grepl("^CS_Con$", Treatment_Statusgroup2), "CS_Con",
                                                                                ifelse(grepl("^CS_PNS$", Treatment_Statusgroup1) | grepl("^CS_PNS$", Treatment_Statusgroup2), "CS_PNS", NA))))

keepscols2 <- c("p.value", "Sexgroup1", "group1", "group2")
stattest2_keep <- stattest2_addgroup2col[keepscols2]

stattest2_keep$matchypos <- corttestunitedmutated_filter_males$ypos[match(stattest1_keep$group2,corttestunitedmutated_filter_males$Treatment_Status)]


c.d.Sex. <- c(stattest2_keep$Sexgroup1)
yposition <- c(stattest2_keep$matchypos)
group1 <- c(stattest2_keep$group1)
group2 <- c(stattest2_keep$group2)
p.value <- c(stattest2_keep$p.value)
asterisk <- c(ifelse(stattest2_keep$p.value<0.10 & stattest2_keep$p.value>0.05, paste("~"),
                     ifelse(stattest2_keep$p.value<0.05 & stattest2_keep$p.value>0.001, paste("*"),
                            ifelse(stattest2_keep$p.value<0.001 & stattest2_keep$p.value>0.0001, paste("**"),
                                   ifelse(stattest2_keep$p.value<0.0001, paste("***"), NA)))))

finalstattest2 <- data.frame(c.d.Sex., yposition, group1, group2, p.value, asterisk)

finalstattest2$yposition <- as.numeric(as.character(finalstattest2$yposition))
stattest2 <- na.omit(finalstattest2)
stattest2nrow <- nrow(stattest2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a lot of what you are doing here would be avoided if you had assigned unique ID's to each and every distinct instace of your experiment (I'm calling each row like that because it's unclear to me what they actually represent).

Assuming that each row were uniquely identified and that the elements of the first data.frame are a subset of the second's elements, all ID's found in `corttestunitedmutated2` (nrow = 8) would be contained in `posthocsepkeep2` (nrow = 28).

Next, you would only have to filter out each dataframe separately by desired characteristics (sex, Treatment Status, etc) and only then joining them by the ID. This would ensure that every `yposition` would be linked with its proper `p.value`, both solving your present problem and future one's, given that this solution is generally applicable.

Now, some notes on the actual coding: I personally think that using `ifelse` and `grepl` the way you're using them makes the coding a bit confusing. I suggest using `subset` or manual manipulation e.g. `data = data[data$x == 'yyy',-c(2,5,6)]` (which translates to saying: give me every row from column 'x' that says 'yyy', minus columns 2,5 and 6).

And to join data.frames, I suggest `package(dyplr)` join functions.

Hope this somehow helps.